# two 15 amp outlets to pigtail 30 amp?

Tags: wiring

I just bought a killer electric chainsaw.  Very powerful, fast and draws a FULL 15 amps.  I keep tripping the 15 amp breaker at the box in the basement.  It's a LONG run of extension cord (50' 10 guage) but its also some 80 feet to the panel so the wire is probably, what 14 gauge to the panel in my walls?  Maybe that's whats tripping the breaker.  I'm cutting BIG ROUNDS so the saw is working hard for like 2-3 full minutes and that's when the circuit breaker says, "too much".  I have to take frequent breaks every 30 seconds to let the breaker cool before I can resume work.

The outlet at the side of the house has 2 15 amp circuits, one to each plug, like a kitchen in newer home construction.  The outlet is GFI protected.  Can I pigtail 2 male plugs and wire a single female to the males? That would give me 30 amps?  I won't overload the extension cord.  It's really heavy duty and I won't overload the wiring in the house, 2 15 amp circuits.

My home is finished and basement done, I can't run a new wire to the back yard. Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement.

Comment: Isn't this a legitimate question that other people might have?  I think we should keep it here (perhaps with some editing to make it clearer), and keep the answer that you absolutely cannot do that.

Comment: @Kris "There's no such thing as a stupid question"™. There are however crispy homeowners, who were too proud/afraid/stupid to ask.

Comment: This.  This is why you don't finish basements.

Comment: Treat the finished basement like a real electrician - a place that needs wiring done, and later someone (else, in their case) can patch and paint.

Comment: @Tester101 Not sure what part of my comment would make you say "Stupid", not that it matters as it has been deleted by you or other admin.  At any rate, the OP seemed somewhat knowledgeable enough with electricity viz. two circuits in a kitchen, and in the same breath ask if its okay to pigtail two male plugs seemed, well, obvious disrespect for safety.

Comment: @Kris it's just a saying. I didn't find your comment offensive, I just don't think the question deserved to be closed.

Answer (score 8):

No, you absolutely cannot do that.

For starters, they will be on different legs of your hydro connection. You will create a short circuit.  There is 240v between the hot wires of those plugs. Even if they were on the same leg, it's still not allowed or advisable, because there is no way to make sure they share the load evenly.  Either way, you'll end up damaging your circuit breakers by continually tripping them, or start a fire.

What you need is to run a new 15 or 20 amp circuit with appropriate gauge wire (which might be thicker depending on length of the run) outside.  Since you know you'll be using long extension cords with it, I'd add the length of my longest extension cord when calculating the length of the run, and see if that makes you need to upsize the wire further.

Comment: "Hydro connection"?

Comment: @isherwood OP must be from Canada. They call the electrical utility "hydro", I'm guessing because most of their power comes from hydroelectric?

Comment: @isherwood Yup, Canuck here.  We call it hydro...dunno why, that's just what we do, eh?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other reasons: when you wire two male connectors together you end up with an exposed energized male terminal after you plug the first one in, that is why they are called **widowmakers**. Do not do this; even if you are careful, someone else who is unaware of the danger might try to use it.

Comment: Yes I understand this and would use the setup ONLY for the odd time I'm using the saw at maximum power cutting large rounds.  Small stuff, no problem, the saw does not run long enough to trip the breaker.  I think a 15 amp circuit can give 17-18 amps for a few seconds.  I need about 16 or 17 continuous over a minute or two.

Answer (score 2):

What you're up against is the infernally small size of US electrical service - 1800 watts.  European countries get between 3100 and 3600 watts at any random receptacle.  However, Americans have an ace up our sleeve that'll let us bring up to 4800W to a receptacle.

Ganging both circuits to serve one receptacle is out of the question.  It is a bad practice for a dozen reasons, unworkable due to GFCI, and utterly impracticable absent an isolation transformer rigged in a way that would really need engineering supervision (i.e. Your institution has a staff of electricians directly overseeing this setup, as such, I won't go into details.)

There are several ways to solve this.

### Turn off the *other* loads on the circuit

Seriously.  Are you 100% sure you know every outlet on the circuit and are ypu positive there aren't any other loads also burdening the circuit?  Because if there are, it would explain everything.

### Bigger cables the whole way

You have the right idea with a 10 AWG extension cord.  You just need to go all the way back to the service panel with it, so you are not relying on that long run of skimpy 14 AWG built into the house.

More likely than not, there is a receptacle *directly underneath your service panel*.  This is the electrician's outlet, when he wired the house, he "hot-wired" this receptacle so it was energized when nothing else was.  And then he ran extension cords for his tools and lights.  When he was nearly done, he punched it down into its own circuit breaker.  Good chance it's 20A.   That is a great receptacle to use.

### Rewire the faraway receptacle for 240V; get a transformer.

America *does* have a standard for 240V and it's as good as Europe's.  It's just rarely used.  Doubling the haul voltage cuts current flow in half, and cuts haulage losses by 3/4.  15A at 240V transforms to 30A at 120V - more than enough.  In fact 16 AWG extension cords would suffice if operating at 240V.  The goal would be move the transformer as close to the work as practical, though your excellent 10 AWG extension cord will be perfectly adequate to haul 120V long distances, don't alter it.

Assuming the long-run receptacle you use is 15A, I'm not sure whether it's MWBC or not, it makes no difference.  Cap the neutral, convert that circuit to 240V and stick NEMA 6-15 outlets there.

If it's dual 14/2 or 14/2/2, even better - those are two separate circuits, leave one 120V and make the other 240V by taping its white wire on both ends and connecting it to a 2-pole 240V breaker of same amperage.   And fit a dual NEMA 5 and 6 receptacle - they make those.   Likewise you would change the ends on an extension cord to NEMA 6.

Now for the 240 to 120 transformer.  This is a little tricky.  The cheapie step-up/down transformers are dodgy because they don't isolate, and the "common" side is presumed to be neutral.  In North American 240V, both legs are hot, no neutral.  On the other hand, these things come with a Schuko plug, which is non-polarized, so in Europe you never know which leg will be neutral.

A better choice is a true isolating transformer, such as a 2 KVA 240/480-120/240 transformer meant for small service installations.  Jumper one side for 240 and the other for 120, obviously.  Since this secondary is isolated, a single ground fault will not kill you.   A GFCI on the output would be nice, though.

The ideal choice, hard to source in the USA, would be the 110V style of power used in UK construction sites.  They use an isolation transformer, as I described in the last paragraph, but the 110V side *has a center-tap*, which they ground.  As a result, even if the tool has a ground fault, it is only 55V from earth, which is not likely to be lethal. I don't think you could simply import a UK construction transformer, becuase they are made for 50-cycle operations.

Comment: Harper, my house does not have an extra 20-A "electrician's receptacle" below the panel. What percent of houses do have that? Around here during construction equipment is powered by a temporary service drop to a meter on a temporary post in the yard.

Comment: @JimStewart most that I've seen but I don't deal much with brand new houses.  The temp service drop on the pole seems to be a recent idea.

Comment: My understanding is that a transformer designed for 50Hz should generally be fine at 60Hz, it's going the other way that can sometimes be a problem due to core saturation. I'd think the main issue with trying to import a UK "yellow brick" transformer would be the postage costs.

Answer (score -1):

Use an extension cord through a window to a 20-A circuit somewhere in the house.

Or get a gasoline generator that can deliver sufficient current to power the chainsaw.

**EDIT**
I believe the Y connection of two circuits on the same leg to the same load would trip a GFCI. I made a neutral to neutral test connection in my garage and it tripped the GFCI.

I have a 20-A circuit with GFCI duplex receptacle in one wall of my garage. Nearby is another duplex receptacle on the same leg but a different circuit (15-A no GFCI). I plugged an extension cord into the GFCI receptacle and inserted a paper clip halfway into the **NEUTRAL** side of the female end of the cord. I brought the end of the extension cord up to the other wall receptacle and pushed the end of the paper clip into the **NEUTRAL** of the other receptacle.

The GFCI immediately tripped. No sparks, no drama, just tripped.  I could test the hots the same way, but don't feel like doing it. Testing of the two hots with a VOM shows they are on the same leg (~0.1 V reading), but I'm not going to chance that I have not thought it through.

Comment: If you test the two receptacles of the duplex receptacle and find that they are on the same leg, then it is not clear to me why it would not be OK to connect them in parallel to the same load with a Y-extension cord. Does the code prohibit this? Not hard wired, but with an extension cord. Would this trip the GFCI?

Comment: You never want to do this. Trying to run two circuits in parallel you cannot be sure that the wiring, connections, circuit breakers and voltage feed will be identical. As a result one circuit almost always ends up sourcing more power than the other. At high current that circuit will trip its breaker first followed soon by tripping the second breaker as it sees the full load on the second circuit. The only thing to do that is safe is to run a single circuit with a suitably sized wire through a single circuit breaker sized to match the capacity of the installed wiring.

Comment: @JimStewart it would be ok if you were in Japan... At a nuclear reactor site... that just got hit by a tsunami... And the work is emergent... And the responsible electrican's team is overseeing... But for a random citizen to ding-dong such a setup, that's just a good way to kill somebody or burn a house down.   Not least, the neutrals are not fused!!

Comment: Karas and Harper, I am not disputing your statements but getting full explanation of the details. The Honda website says their generators (or at least some of them) can be placed in parallel to increase available current so I wondered why not two residential branch circuits on the same leg? It would seem that if either circuit is protected with a GFCI breaker, this would trip the breaker., right?

Comment: Why get a generator? Surely a gas powered chainsaw is cheaper.

Comment: The idea would be that one already has the electric chain saw and it is much quieter than a gasoline one.  Then if one gets a gasoline generator one may find other uses for the generator. As far as I am concerned the use of "leaf" blowers and gasoline chain saws is an *outrage* in a residential area.

Comment: @JimStewart Generators designed to be placed in parallel have extra work done to them to make sure they share the load equally.  On modern ones that usually means extra control circuitry to make sure the generators stay in sync and make sure they start up together properly.

Comment: Getting a gas powered generator would defeat the purpose of getting an electric chainsaw.  I want quiet as I'm in a residential neighborhood.  To the other gentleman, I'd sure like to plug into (through a window) a 20 amp circuit.  I don't have one that I know of.

Comment: Why don't you open the door on the panel and view the labeling on the breakers? Surely you have some 20-A circuits?Say in the kitchen or in a bathroom. What about the receptacle for the clothes washer? If it is a 20-A circuit, wait until the washer is not being used and plug a heavy extension cord into it. Maybe the disposer is on a 20-A circuit. Presumably you are using this chain saw only intermittently and can work round other uses of a 20-A circuit. Long term add one or more 20-A circuits in your garage.

Comment: So, @Kevin, what are you going to do?

Comment: I'll have a look at the panel and see if I have any 20A.  I'd love the pig tail setup but from what people are saying, I may have a problem.

Comment: The Y connection of the two receptacles to the same load would only work if they were on the same leg. Did you ever test the voltage hot to hot to see if you got ~0 V or got ~240 V? Even if they were on the same leg (0 V hot to hot) connecting the two hots would almost certainly trip the GFCI, if you have one on either circuit. I think it is established here that this would not work. **If you test the two and find they are on the same leg**, and don't want to make up a Y and have it not work, then you could get a 1 ft length of #12 or #14 wire and stick one end in each of the hots!

Comment: Be sure everyone, including the dog, is out of the house if you would do the "hot-to-hot" GFCI test and be sure your health and life insurance policies are up to date.

Comment: Come to think about it a safer test that it would probably fail would be to connect neutral to neutral of the two receptacles. This would probably trip the GFCI and you'd have no hot wires to deal with.  This would prove that a Y connector would not work with GFCI.

Comment: My reasoning is that if I understand GFCI correctly, it compares the current in the hot and neutral conductors. A  difference greater than ~10 mA trips the breaker. Any alternate current paths (which a Y connector would create) would almost certainly yield a difference greater than the trip value.

Comment: See edit to my answer. I made a neutral to neutral connection in my garage and it tripped the GFCI.  This is without any added load.

Comment: @Tester101 electric is definitely the better way to run a chainsaw, *if* you can get the heavy wires to it.  Jim the Honda generators' ability to parallel definitely qualifies as "responsible electrician team overseeing", in that this function is integrated into the generator.  What they're doing is using a digital inverter with variable generator speed, having done so it is easy to synchronize the inverters' phase.

Comment: @Harper better in what way?  It may be quieter, but I can't think of any other advantages.

Comment: @Tester101 you are taking for granted things which have long become habit, like futzing with cantankerous carburetors, rebuilding short-lived engines, hard starting in the cold, and having to buy both fuel and 2-cycle oil and premix them in a can which you carry around. In my experience all those things are much worse, and my experience is with a brand new topgrade Stihl. The only redeeming quality of gas engines is they run out of fuel, which can be used as a memory device to remind you to sharpen and add chain oil.  I fill my Stihl's gas tank halfway for that reason,

Comment: @Harper They sell [pre-mixed ethanol-free fuel](http://trufuel50.com/product-info/), which eliminates mixing and futzing with the carburetor. And I don't have to lug around, lay out, or roll up an extension cord. Also, no waiting for batteries to charge (if you've got a cordless saw).  But I guess to each his own.